# Removing a sequence inside of brackets from a string

Tags: sql, regex, string, google-bigquery

I have some data with a field that looks somewhat like this:

> (1234) abcd, efgh (5678)

I need to remove the characters inside the brackets, so that my output looks like this:

> abcd, efgh

I tried using `REGEXP_REPLACE("(1234) abcd, efgh (5678)","[(.*?)]" , "")`, this however only removes the brackets and leaves the characters inside. I am not really familiar with regular expressions. Can you help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have tried this already, unfortunately it does not work. Big Query throws me an error: 
`Syntax error: Illegal escape sequence: \( at [1:51]`

Comment: Just escape the parentheses with ``\\``, like `REGEXP_REPLACE("(1234) abcd, efgh (5678)","\\(.*?\\)" , "")`. Also, you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE("(1234) abcd, efgh (5678)","\\([^()]*\\)" , "")`

Comment: nice, thank you!